# multi-select with jetpack compose mvvm arch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of items (it comes from an API) and I want to create an MVVM arch app that uses Jetpack compose to view the list and allow the user to select items (using checkbox).
The thing is, I need to validate the selected items by passing them to a different API (this will happen in the ViewModel).

heres's what I did:

fragment.kt

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, 
val selectedList: List<item> = listOf()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
  setup()
}

private fun setup() {
  setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
     setContent {
         MdcTheme(readTypography = true) {
            val itemsResponse by viewModel.ItemsResponse.collectAsState()
            ItemsListPage(
                items = itemsResponse,
                sList = selectedList,
                onSelect = { item, flag -> onItemSelected(item, flag) },
                onNext = { navigateToNext() }
            )
         }
     }
}


private fun onItemSelected(item: Item, flag: Boolean) {
  if (flag) {
    if (!selectedList.contains(item))
        selectedList.add(item)
  } else
        selectecList.remove
}


private navigateToNext(){
  if (selectedLIst.isNotEmpty()) {
     viewModel.setSelectedList(selectedList)
     // navigate
  } else {
    // some dialog to alert the user
  }
}
```

And here is ItemsListPage.kt:

```kotlin
// ....

LazyColumn(
    modifier.weight(2f).padding(4.dp)
) {
  //check if the list is empty and show empty screen if so
  
  items(items) {
    val isSelected = sList.contains(it)
    CheckBoxCard(content = it, isSelected = isSelected, onCheck = {item,flag -> onCheck(item,flag)})
  }
  
  // other stuff
}


/// CheckBoxCard function:

var checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(isSelected) }

val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        interactionSource
            .interactions
            .filter { it is PressInteraction.Press }
            .collect {
                checkedState = !checkedState
         }
}


Card {
 
  // content ....
  
  Checkbox(
   interactionSource = interactionSource,
    checked = checkedState,
    onCheckChange = {
      checkedState != checkedState
      
      onCheck(item, checkedState)
    }
  )
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that some items are duplicated in the selected List and sometimes they don't even get added to the list. I tried to make a data class with the Item and isSelect = false by default but then another issue appeared which is that the checkmark recomposes when I scroll down and the check is removed

Comment: try to make checkmark variable `rememberSaveable` and if the duplicate data is storing in the list then change the `list` to `set`.

Comment: @JayantKumar but when I uncheck the item it does not get removed from the list, this is causing the duplication